# Ember CLI -- How do I modify node modules?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

Simple question...

So I've installed a node module and I want to make some tweaks to it, but any changes I make to the code are not reflected in my app.  Do I need to rebuild it manually or something once I edit it?

Comment: Live reload doesn't observe `node_modules` you ll have to rebuild (open a file from your app and just save it), be careful with editing the modules though you ll end up having to support it and/or get locked to a version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bad habit to change third party modules. You won't be able to update it. The better way may be to overwrite it somehow in your application (e.g. overwrite methods in intializers, patch during the build process, etc).

But if you still need to make changes exactly in the module code, you may have to rebuild it according to instructions in the module repository readme file. You would have to switch to the module directory in order to do that.

Comment: Components, for example, can be easily overwritten in application by defining a component with the same name. The same with templates.

Comment: Great to know.  Thanks!